# How do I write a .txt file with the same name as the input file?

Tags: python

I provide a video as an input to my system, it processes the video and then it writes some information into a .txt file. How do I name the .txt file exactly the same as the video file name?

```
    # getting input video
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True,
                    help="path to input video")
    ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True,
                    help="path to output video")
    
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    
    # capturing the video frames from input video
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["input"])

    # writing the output folder and txt file
    
    outputfile_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'output')
    if not os.path.exists(outputfile_dir):
        os.makedirs(outputfile_dir)
        os.chmod(outputfile_dir , 0o777)
    outputFilename=os.path.join(outputfile_dir,"demofile.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pathlib import Path


def to_txt(filename: Path) -> Path:
    """Changes a filename for an arbitrary
    file to a filename with a *.txt suffix.
    """
    
    return filename.parent / f'{filename.stem}.txt'


filename = Path('dir1/videos/my_video-12.avi')
txt_file = to_txt(filename)
print(txt_file)
```

## Explanation

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is part of Python's standard library and provides object-oriented access to path-like objects. I.e. you can hadle file and directory paths as objects with methods and properties for common operations on those types of objects. For further details, read the docs.

What the function `to_txt()` does is, it takes such a path-like object, namely the path to the video file as input. It then extracts the paths to the video's parent directory by accessing the property `filename.parent`, which returns another `pathlib.Path` object to the directory containing the file. So for any file named `dir1/videos/my_video-12.avi`, this part returns `dir1/videos`.

You can access a `pathlib.Path`'s file name without the leading directories and without its suffix via the property `Path.stem`.
In the f-string `f'{filename.stem}.txt'`, we access this property and concatenate it with our new suffix `'.txt'`, so that for any file named `dir1/videos/my_video-12.avi`, this part returns `my_video-12.txt`.

As you can see, what we're missing is the path to the folder containing the file, which we extracted earlier.
By using the `/` operator, we can join `pathlib.Path` objects with other `pathlib.Path`, or as in this case, with `str` objects, so that the result will be a `pathlib.Path` object with the full path to the file on the right hand side of `/`. Which leaves us with `dir1/videos/my_video-12.txt`.

Comment: Thanks @richard, I wonder if you could explain to_txt function in more details? I do not understand.

Comment: The `to_txt()` function takes a parameter `filename` of type `Path` (shown by `filename:Path`) and will return a value of type `Path` (shown by `-> Path`). Next the file name's parent is taken which is basically the folder the file is in (so if you have a path such as `a/b/c.txt` it returns `a/b`). Then the function adds the file stem which is basically the file name without it's filetype (so if you have a path such as `a/b/c.txt` it returns `c`) to the parent with the `/` which is used to add `Path` objects.